# Странность вывода текста в цикле

Tags: perl

Вот сейчас заметил, что если написать

```
use strict;
use warnings;
foreach my $value (10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 'БУМ...'){
    print $value;
    sleep(1);   
}
```

То программа ждёт, когда пройдёт 11 секунд и выводит всё содержимое. А если изменить

```
use strict;
use warnings;
foreach my $value (10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 'БУМ...'){
    print $value, "\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

То тогда всё нормально (каждую секунду выводится цифра). Так вот почему в первом случае текст сохраняется в "буфер", а во втором сразу выводится? Ведь по сути разницы между ними никакой...

Comment: В общем, погоду делает перенос строки `\n`, как я понял.

Comment: @alexlz, оу, старый добрый autoflush! Вызвал ностальгию по старым временам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А если так?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
$|=1;
foreach my $value (10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 'БУМ...'){
    print $value;
    sleep(1);   
}
```

Comment: Про это я знаю , вопрос то в том , почему при добавлении /\n происходит сразу вывод в поток

Comment: Это называется line buffering -- буфферизация на строку.